# Convert text string to octal string

Tags: java

I need to convert a text string to an WinANSIEncoding compliant (Windows code page 1252) octal string (using Java).

"`André`" should become "`101 156 144 162 351`" or `"\101\156\144\162\351".`

I could use a simple string search and replace for each character in the list of allowed characters, but this would probably not be the fastest solutions.

Does anyone know how this should be done?

Thanx

TM

Ps
https://cryptii.com/text-octal

Comment: Hi TM. What have you tried so far?

Comment: [Map ?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Take the [tour], make sure to read [ask], and go through this [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) to make sure your question meets the quality standards that will make it more likely it will be answered rather than downvoted and closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`toOctalString(int i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toOctalString-int-) will help :

---

1. Using `Streams`

   ```
   String str ="André";
   String toOctal = str.chars().boxed().map(Integer::toOctalString)
                                       .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

   System.out.println(toOctal); // 101 156 144 162 351
   ```

   [***Workable Demo***](https://ideone.com/xqiTQ1)

---

2. Basic loop

   ```
   String str ="André";
   String toOctal ="";
   for(char c : str.toCharArray()){
       toOctal += Integer.toOctalString(c)+" ";
   }
   System.out.println(toOctal);
   ```